# Sum() different columns according to row values

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table given below in the picture:
[image]

What i want to do is `sum(3R00)` `sum(3R01)` `sum(3R02)` & `sum(3R03)` and group them by months also adding values for the same month as a single value. Like first two rows of the table are from the Month 03 Year 2013. So i want their sum combined as a single value.

The ideal output for the year 2013 grouped by months should give me something liek this:

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried. And what is the issue you are getting in your query!

Comment: I tried this: `SELECT id, Month,SUM(3R00) AS 3R00,SUM(3R01) AS 3R01 FROM varcosts Where Year = 2014 GROUP BY Month` The issue is i am not able to sum the rows according to the months.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL?

Comment: i am using PhpMyadmin

Comment: You mean `sum(3R00) + sum(3R01) + sum(3R02) + sum(3R03)`?

Comment: @IbrahimNadir Please show us what you expect to be an output for the data you posted in your question.

Comment: OK am making the output table to make it easier for u to understand

Comment: @Luaan yes but the same month's values must be added up as a single row. Like in the table the first two rows must be combined and the other months just grouped by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this query may help you

```
SELECT Month,
    YEAR,
    SUM(3R00) one,
    SUM(3R01) two,
    SUM(3R02) three,
    SUM(3R03) four
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Month,
    YEAR
```

Comment: i couldn't explain myself well. Maybe the question is clearer now.. sorry about that.

Comment: @IbrahimNadir giving you desired results?

Comment: @Radu i need to combine the same month values too

Comment: @IbrahimNadir Please edit your question and post what you expect to be displayed.

Comment: No haseeb. The desired results must add up the values for the same month. This does group them but i want the same month values be combined

Comment: i think above query is doing the same. can you please post the schema on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and try to explain your question with desired results

Comment: @Haseeb Please check the desired output now. The output from your query isn't combining the same months together.

Comment: @IbrahimNadir can you please export your table schema with sample inserts and share as till now i found no problem in SQL

Comment: For me this query makes the expected output : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b829/3

Comment: I'm sorry haseeb. Thats not possible for me. The problem in your sql is pretty simple. Please read my question. Your query would return to me the first two rows as separate ones and i want the same month be combined.

Comment: I messed up! Thank you! I was confusing the years!!! Although i tried that query from the start myself. :( Thanks a lot guys!!